# Use the contrapositive of an hypothesis in Coq

Tags: coq

My current hypotheses and goal are:

```
1 subgoal
x : Entity
H : ~ P x x -> exists z : Entity, P z x /\ ~ O z x
______________________________________(1/1)
P x x
```

I would like to apply the contrapositive of H, which, I think, is `(~ exists z : Entity, P z x /\ ~ O z x) -> P x x`. I would obtain the goal `~ exists z : Entity, P z x /\ ~ O z x`, that is equivalent to `forall z : Entity, ~ P z x \/ O z x`.

I have several questions: 1) how to make a new hypothesis which is the contrapositive of H; 2) once I applied the contrapositive, how to rewrite `~ exists z : Entity, P z x /\ ~ O z x` into `forall z : Entity, ~ P z x \/ O z x`?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using classical logic inside Coq.

```
Require Import Classical.

Check imply_to_or.
Check not_ex_all_not.
```

For example,

```
Goal forall (P Q : nat -> Prop) x, (~ P x -> (exists x, Q x)) -> P x.
intros P Q x H.
destruct (imply_to_or _ _ H) as [H1| [y H1]].
- now apply NNPP.
- contradict H1.
```